# Specifying Timeout with PageFactory [Selenium]

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I know that we can clean-up page objects by covering properties by [FindsBy] attributes and using PageFactory to initialize all the elements. We define such properties like this:

```
[FindsBy(How = How.CssSelector, Using = "input[type='submit']")]
public IWebElement SignIn { get; private set; }
```

And we can initialize all such properties by calling:

```
PageFactory.InitElements(_driver, this);
```

The first question which comes to my mind is how the searching process will run? How many retries, any timeouts applied? I assume that there will be only one try with a zero-timeout.

Is that possible to combine PageFactory approach with a custom searching process such as 3 tries for searching with an ExpectedCondition being set and so on?

Answer (score 2):

Adding to Ashish's answer, I use one of two different methods.  For regular Selenium, I use:

```
    PageFactory.initElements(new AjaxElementLocatorFactory(driver, 15), this);
```

For Appium, I use:

```
    PageFactory.initElements(new AppiumFieldDecorator(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(30)), this);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use AppiumFieldDecorator (a JAVA Library),

```
app = new AppiumFieldDecorator(driver, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
PageFactory.initElements(app, this);

app.resetImplicitlyWaitTimeOut(0, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

this will going to set implicit time wait at the time of your PageFactory design pattern.
I hope this might help you as your question says [FindBy] thats in C# but following same approach of JAVA,

```
@FindBy("your another locator")
WebElement e2;
```

waits for the rendering and for the default duration time.

```
@WithTimeout(timeOut = time, timeUnit = unit)
@FindBy("your locator")
WebElement e;
```

here you can provide the timeout timing set via @WithTimeout.